# innosetup, uninstall shared service

Tags: service, inno-setup, uninstallation, shared

I am installing and uninstalling some service apps via InnoSetup's code section as below.

```
ShellExec('', ExpandConstant('{app}\') + dExeName, '/install /silent', '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ErrorCode);
    ....
ShellExec('', ExpandConstant('{app}\') + dExeName, '/uninstall /silent', '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ErrorCode);
```

Now I have a seperate application which using the same service. both applications' installer installs and uninstalls those services.

I need a solution that the uninstaller should not uninstall if other application still exists on the computer.

Faruk.
Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Both installers should set an entry in the Registry using the `[Registry]` Section (http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=registrysection) setting the flag `uninsdeletekey`.

In both uninstallers you can check then whether the other application is still installed by doing something like

```
 if not RegKeyExists(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'Software\Faruk\OtherSoftwareName') then
 begin
    // The key exists
    ShellExec('', ExpandConstant('{app}\') + dExeName, '/uninstall /silent', '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ErrorCode); 
 end;
```